# Add a bit value to a string

Tags: c++, bit

I am trying to send a packet over a network and so want it to be as small as possible (in terms of size).

Each of the input *can* contain a common prefix substring, like `ABCD`.  In such cases, I just wanna send a single bit say, `1` denoting that the current string has the same prefix `ABCD` and append it to the remaining string.  So, if the string was `ABCDEF`, I will send `1EF`; if it was `LKMPS`, I wish to send the string `LKMPS` as is.

Could someone please point out how I could add a bit to a string?

Edit:  I get that adding a `1` to a string does not mean that this `1` is a bit - it is just a character that I added to the string.  And that exactly is my question - for each string, how do I send a bit denoting that the prefix matches?  And then send the remaining part of the string that is different?

Comment: Why `-1`?  Please explain.  I'll edit.

Comment: The reason for `-1` is probably because you have shown no effort of solving this yourself. This is not a code writing website. It's a Q&A based website

Comment: Not downvoted by me, but the question is not clear. Please add some code to show what you are trying to do. What datatypes are you using? A `std::string` cannot have only a single bit appended. You would have to convert it into a character. As written the question cannot be answered.

Comment: IP (the internet protocol), which carries most network packets these days (and all internet messages, which is probably what you mean) sends data packets which contain a whole number of (8 bit) bytes.  It sounds like you want to send some packet with a number of bits which isn't a multiple of 8. If that's the case, IP can't oblige.  If that's not what you want, you will need to rephrase your question to make it clearer what you actually do want.

Comment: Wasn't me, but if I had to guess it would be that "1EF" does not represent a bit added to a string, but rather a string with 3 bytes, the first of which is the character `1`.  So the question looks unclear due to confusion about whether you know what a bit is, the fact that we don't normally think of putting "bits into strings", and that network layers at the software level transport _bytes_.

Comment: @Fureeish, I have mentioned the approach that I am thinking of.  What other effort do you want?  Code?  It is just two lines, besides being trivial (just adding `1` to a string!)

Comment: Case in point.  You are not even talking about bits.

Comment: @paddy, yes, I have edited the question.  How do I send a bit?  And then what about the remaining part of the string (suffix) that is different?

Comment: @wally, could you please elaborate - you would have to convert it into a character?  How could I then add a bit to it?

Comment: (1) Stop calling it a bit.  (2) That depends on your design, exactly what data can be in the strings, such that a number and string component can always be correctly parsed at the other end, and how you are storing the substitution prefixes in your program in the first place

Comment: What datatypes are you using? What is the C++ type that you are trying to send? What is the type that the networking function accepts?

Comment: In order to provide useful suggestions on [what sounds a lot like "How do I compress data?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) we need to know what the data is and how it's likely to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In common networking hardware, you won't be able to send individual bits. And most architectures cannot address individual bits, either.

However, you can still minimize the size as you want by using one of the bits that you may not be using. For instance, if your strings contain only 7-bit ASCII characters, you could use the highest bit to encode the information you want in the first byte of the string.

For example, if the first byte is:

```
0b01000001 == 0x41 == 'A'
```

Then set the highest bit using `|`:

```
(0b01000001 | 0x80) == 0b11000001 == 0xC1
```

To test for the bit, use `&`:

```
(0b01000001 & 0x80) == 0
(0b11000001 & 0x80) != 0
```

To remove the bit (in the case where it was set) to get back the original first byte:

```
(0b11000001 & 0x7F) == 0b01000001 == 0x41 == 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a buffer for use in your communications protocol, it should generally not be an `std::string`. Standard strings are not intended for  use as buffers; and they can't generally be prepended in-place with anything.

It's possible that you may be better served by an `std::vector<std::byte>`; or by a (compile-time-fixed-size) [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Or, again, a class of your own making. That is especially true if you want your "in-place" prepending of bits or characters to not merely keep the same span of memory for your buffer, but to actually not move any of the existing data. For that, you'd need twice the maximum length of the buffer, and start it at the middle, so you can either append or prepend data without shifting anything - while maintaining bit-resolution "pointers" to the effective start and end of the full part of the buffer. This is would be readily achievable with, yes you guessed it, your own custom buffer class.

Comment: This is wise advice, but I'm not sure it's an answer to any of the questions posted.

Comment: What do you mean `std::string` can't be prepended in-place? An `std::vector` can't be preprended either without copying -- but I am not sure why you would want to prepend anything in this context.

Comment: @Acorn: Yes I'm sure. As for an `std::vector` - you could reserve enough space to ensure a prepending would be in-place.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I'm suggesting what OP should do in order to address the challenge OP is facing.

Comment: @einpoklum: Sure about what? My question was why would you want to prepend? As for `std::vector`: reserving space only avoids allocations, but not the copying/moving of the entire data.

Comment: @Acorn: I'm sure `std::string` can't generally be prepended in-place. There's short string optimization, and even without it - there will likely be reallocation which you can't control like with `std::vector`. At any rate, by "in-place" I meant that the buffer won't move. Of course you would need to shift the rest of the elements forward. But let me clarify that in the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum: I didn't ask whether you were sure about that :) Anyway, I see what you meant by "prepending" now. In C++17 it is guaranteed that you could also edit the string in-place (and in many implementations it was already like that even before C++17).

Answer (score -2):

I think the smallest amount of memory you can work with is 8 bits.

If you wanted to operate with bits, you could specify 8 prefixes as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum message_header {
    prefix_on = 1 << 0,
    bitdata_1 = 1 << 1,
    bitdata_2 = 1 << 2,
    bitdata_3 = 1 << 3,
    bitdata_4 = 1 << 4,
    bitdata_5 = 1 << 5,
    bitdata_6 = 1 << 6,
    bitdata_7 = 1 << 7,
};

int main() {
    uint8_t a(0);

    a ^= prefix_1;

    if(a & prefix_on) {
        std::cout << "prefix_on" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That being said, networks pretty fast nowadays so I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Since you have no idea what architecture this person is working with, neither your first nor last statements are actually valid.  You've also kinda missed the point.  Using bit flags the way you are implies combinations are possible, but that's not required so it's actually _more_ wasteful than using a simple token character.  Sure, you might use a high-bit in the datastream to indicate that a prefix token is used, but that completely depends on the user's data ranges which have not been provided.  Note that you will get downvoted when providing naive answers to unclear questions.

Comment: @paddy yeah, I guess you're right about prefixes, but that's not what I was thinking. Perhaps you'd be interested in a more abstract question related to the messaging protocol efficiency. I'll edit the code. Regarding down-voting naive answers, I'll go back to the comment by another user regarding "be careful criticizing something that is used by millions of people". I'm interested to know what "architecture" would make it invalid though and why, thanks.